# how parentForm Reference is null?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, user-controls

I have an application in which i have added a usercontrol on the form.
When i  check `this.parentForm` in the userControl constructor it gives a null reference

My userControl Code is like

```
public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (this.ParentForm != null)//ParentReference is null
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hi");//Does Not get Called
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the control is being created, it won't have been added to a form yet - so of course the parent form will be null.

Even if you'd normally write it as:

```
// Where form might be "this"
form.Controls.Add(new UserControl1());
```

You should think of it as:

```
UserControl1 tmp = new UserControl1();
form.Controls.Add(tmp);
```

Now your constructor is being executed in the *first* line, but the first mention of `form` is in the *second* line... so how could the control have any visibility of it?

You should probably be handling the [`ParentChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parentchanged.aspx) event instead, and taking appropriate action then. (Apologies if you're not using Windows Forms - I'm sure there's an equivalent for other UI frameworks; next time it would be useful if you could state what you're using in the question.)

Comment: So how can i get refrence of parnetForm so that i can handle some parent event on the userControl like ReSize?

Comment: @Nilesh As I said, do it in the ParentChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

for what did you added this line no need actually, remove this line

```
 if (this.ParentForm != null)//ParentReference is null

public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            MessageBox.Show("Hi");//Does Not get Called

        }
```

Comment: That is dummy code,i need to hande other code inside if condition.